# Adobe Illustrator raster image dimensions?

Tags: windows, adobe-illustrator

I have a PNG image file with the dimensions 1024px x 1074px when I bring it into illustrator it gives me the dimensions of the image as 768.107px x 805.612px. I even tried to export the image (for web) and this exported a new PNG with the dimensions specified in illustrator (without the decimal). I have tried opening the images directly with illustrator rather that "importing" them and the problem still persists. Why is illustrator making my images smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is probably 96 DPI and Illustrator is normalizing to 72 ("pixel" and "dot" being interchangeable here):

```
1024px / 96 = 768px / 72
```

The standard measure for AI is `pt` which is 1/72 inches.  If your image claims it should be 96 DPI, Illustrator will force every 96 dots down to fit in what it thinks is 1 inch of screen space.

Comment: how do i "fix" it?

Comment: Not sure how to prevent it with Illustrator.  You could use Paint.net to adjust the resolution to 72 (it measures by pixels/inch).

Answer (score 2):

As @hyperslug pointed it out, it is because the Raster Effects Settings of Illustrator. The initial or default is set to 72 ppi, but you can change this behavior. Just go to Effects --> Document Raster Effect Settings --> Others.

[image]